# InstallAllOracleASPNETProviders doesn't work correctly

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, odac

I am using asp.net mvc 3 and oracle database with ODAC1120240Beta_EntityFramework.

I want to do authorization in my site. Database works correctly, I can do everything with Database data, but if I go to `ASP.NET Configuration -> Provider` I see only `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider`.

InstallAllOracleASPNETProviders doesn't work correctly.

All functions, views and packages were created succesully. I do all using [this Oracle Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/installation.htm#BABFFDIE)

Here is part of Oracle Database Output after executing this script from Visual Studio Tools.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ora_vw_aspnet_Applications TO ora_aspnet_Mem_ReportAccess
                                              *
error in string 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'ORA_ASPNET_MEM_REPORTACCESS' does not exist


GRANT SELECT ON ora_vw_aspnet_Users TO ora_aspnet_Mem_ReportAccess
                                       *
error in string 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'ORA_ASPNET_MEM_REPORTACCESS' does not exist


GRANT SELECT ON ora_vw_aspnet_MemUsers TO ora_aspnet_Mem_ReportAccess
                *
error in string 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement using [flow link](http://quysnhat.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/using-membership-with-oracle-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3/).