# How to do form authentification in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, authentication

I am using Oracle Database, what tables I should add and how I can do my MembershipProvider and other providers? Thank you.

I have tried to use Oracle Providers, but have some problems with it. The details is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106321/installalloracleaspnetproviders-doesnt-work-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has providers for asp.net : http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10928_01/IntroOverview.htm